# Openpyxl выдает ошибку Module 'openpyxl' has no 'reader' member

Tags: python, python-3.x, база-данных, excel, openpyxl

```
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.reader.excel.load_workbook(filename="index.xlsx")
print(wb.sheetnames)

wb.active = 0

sheet = wb.active
a = (sheet['A3'].value)
b = (sheet['B3'].value)


c2 = sheet['C2']

c2.value = "TRUE"

wb.save("D:\\Works\\Python\\Piotrowski index\\demo.xlsx")
```

Код ошибки

```
Module 'openpyxl' has no 'reader' member
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо:

```
import openpyxl
```

Используй:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename="index.xlsx")
```

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name 'load_workbook' from partially initialized module 'openpyxl' (most likely due to a circular import) (d:\Works\Python\Piotrowski index\openpyxl.py) 
Спасибо за помощь, ошибка ушла, но появилась новая

Comment: @Niumandzi Нельзя называть свой модуль так же как и тот который пытаешься импортировать d:\Works\Python\Piotrowski index\openpyxl.py<---